# Where can I Find Free TOS or Privacy Policy Templates?

Tags: legal, game-industry

I've come to the point in development where I think I should take care of some of the "cover my butt" things.  In particular, I'm looking for free samples or templates for "terms of service/use" and "privacy policy" statements.

I actually do have my law degree and know something about IP, contracts, etc.  However, it's always better not to reinvent the wheel with these type of industry-wide boilerplate documents.

I couldn't find this answer anywhere on this or other StackExchange sites. Of any legit looking sites, I only found paid templates.

Does anyone know of a good website that offers these templates for free?  I can edit a general one if needed, but it would be best to have some already geared towards an online game.

**UPDATE**

Some promising resources I found out there:

TRUSTe Privacy policy generator:

http://www.truste.com/technology/#labs

I think you are supposed to pay to use the TRUSTe seal or something, but that doesn't stop you from using this as a starting point.  I guess it might help to read their TOS first (LoL).

Legal River TOS / Privacy Policy Generator:

http://terms-of-service-generator.legalriver.com/

http://privacy-policy-generator.legalriver.com/

For now I'll start with these and rework them for my needs.  Would still love to hear if anyone knows of a better one geared towards online games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this useful?  http://www.bennadel.com/coldfusion/privacy-policy-generator.htm

Why not just bite the bullet and pay for one?  You should know (with a law degree) that you want it to be right.

Comment: I'll accept this as best answer and for getting me to use "generator" in my search terms.

Comment: He really is spot on about getting someone with an actual law degree to work with you in creating a privacy policy though.  I would guess that the defense of "But I used this privacy policy generator!  You can't take me to court!" probably won't work out well.

Answer (score 0):

I paid a lawyer to prepare mine, but I felt everything that was included was just boilerplate with language for my games plugged in.

If I were to do it again I would just collect together a series TOS's from other web sites and business from my country, and re write in plain English each point in those TOS's.

I would say a Free TOS would be worth the money you pay for it, and about effective as something you wrote yourself.

Note: The above is bad legal advice, but IANAL and just saying what I would do next time.